# NAudio and ZedGraph Waveform Plotting

Tags: c#, naudio, zedgraph, waveform

```
    int window;
    LineItem myCurve1;
    LineItem myCurve2;
    public void DrawWave(ZedGraphControl zgc)
    {

        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
        WaveFileReader wavFile = new WaveFileReader(open.FileName);
        byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.Length];

        float fileSize = (float)wavFile.Length / 1048576;
        if (fileSize < 2)
            window = 8;
        else if (fileSize > 2 && fileSize < 4)
            window = 16;
        else if (fileSize > 4 && fileSize < 8)
            window = 32;
        else if (fileSize > 8 && fileSize < 12)
            window = 128;
        else if (fileSize > 12 && fileSize < 20)
            window = 256;
        else if (fileSize > 20 && fileSize < 30)
            window = 512;
        else
            window = 2048;

        float[] fbuffer = new float[mainBuffer.Length / window];
        wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            fbuffer[i] = (BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * window));
        }

        double time = wave.TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;
        PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList list2 = new PointPairList();
        for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(i, fbuffer[i]);
        }
        list2.Add(0, 0);
        list2.Add(time, 0);
        if (myCurve1 != null && myCurve2 != null)
        {
            myCurve1.Clear();
            myCurve2.Clear();
        }

        myCurve1 = myPane.AddCurve(null, list1, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        myCurve1.IsX2Axis = true;
        myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve(null, list2, Color.Black, SymbolType.None);
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Invalidate();
    }
```

I have this code to plot waveform in ZedGraph. It works fine except one thing.After drawing a waveform, i choose a new file to draw but i must clear the old one. I tried to define `LineItem` in global so i can write `if(myCruver != null) myCurve.Clear();` this condition.However it does not clear the old drawing. What am i suppose to do to solve this problem?

Comment: I think i should use `PointPairList` instead of `IPointListEdit`. I am not sure but `IPointListEdit` is used for real time data plotting.
`          for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i, fbuffer[i]);
            }
            LineItem curve = myPane.AddCurve("ABC", lst, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int window;
    LineItem myCurve1;
    LineItem myCurve2;
    public void DrawWave(ZedGraphControl zgc)
    {

        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));
        WaveFileReader wavFile = new WaveFileReader(open.FileName);
        byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[wave.Length];

        float fileSize = (float)wavFile.Length / 1048576;
        if (fileSize < 2)
            window = 8;
        else if (fileSize > 2 && fileSize < 4)
            window = 16;
        else if (fileSize > 4 && fileSize < 8)
            window = 32;
        else if (fileSize > 8 && fileSize < 12)
            window = 128;
        else if (fileSize > 12 && fileSize < 20)
            window = 256;
        else if (fileSize > 20 && fileSize < 30)
            window = 512;
        else
            window = 2048;

        float[] fbuffer = new float[mainBuffer.Length / window];
        wave.Read(mainBuffer, 0, mainBuffer.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            fbuffer[i] = (BitConverter.ToSingle(mainBuffer, i * window));
        }

        double time = wave.TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;
        PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
        PointPairList list2 = new PointPairList();
        for (int i = 0; i < fbuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(i, fbuffer[i]);
        }
        list2.Add(0, 0);
        list2.Add(time, 0);
        if (myCurve1 != null && myCurve2 != null)
        {
            myCurve1.Clear();
            myCurve2.Clear();
        }

        myCurve1 = myPane.AddCurve(null, list1, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        myCurve1.IsX2Axis = true;
        myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve(null, list2, Color.Black, SymbolType.None);
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Invalidate();
    }
```

I just separated the `LineItems` of list1 and list2. Now it works fine .